# CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials how to get the username and or password

Tags: c#, .net, credentials, networkcredentials

For debugging purpose I wanted to look in the value of username and password of CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.

I see that there are 2 properties of username and password in CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials and doing

1. CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.username
2. CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.passwrod

does not print anything what should I do?

Comment: have you tried with `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`?